# CSVHelper Dynamic Object Write CsvFile

Tags: c#, .net, csv, export, csvhelper

I am using CSVHelper for import and export operations and here my goal is to drop a table from database if he wants to export a new csv for that item and while doing this I want to export the existing table data from db. So far I have this but when I am sending the dynamic object to **WriteRecords** Function it gives me No properties mapped for the object **Error**. I checked other questions about this and checked documantation of CSVHelper but couldnt understand what I am missing. Here is my code for exporting the data from db. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
                    var item = await itemService.GetAsync(SKU);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        var query = builder.GetDatabaseTablenames();
                        var tableNameList = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query).ToList();
                        if (tableNameList.Contains(SKU))
                        {
                            var tableDataQuery = GetTableDataQuery(SKU);
                            var tableData = context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic(tableDataQuery).ToList();

                            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
                            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                            {
                                csv.WriteRecords(tableData);
                            }

                            var dropQuery = DropTableQuery(SKU);
                            var tableDrop = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dropQuery);
```

Comment: You are going to need to show some of the types of things; you have a lot of code there, but I'm not sure what most of it does.  If you need the schema of the table (so that you can describe it to the CSV helper, you can use a DataReader in your query.  DataReaders have an embedded DataTable within them that describes the schema of the query (column names, types, etc.).  Whenever I've done something like what I think you are describing, I've constructed schema from there.

Comment: Hello there I am not using ADO but Entity